# How can I pass unbound arguments from one script as parameters to another?

Tags: powershell

I have little experience with PowerShell in particular.

I'm trying to refactor some very commonly re-used code into a single script that can be sourced where it's needed, instead of copying and pasting this same code into ***n*** different scripts.

The scenario I'm trying to get looks (I think) like this:

```
#common.ps1:
param(
    # Sure'd be great if clients didn't need to know about these
    $some_params_here
    ...
)

function Common-Func-Uses-Params {
   ...
}

⋮
```

```
# foo/bar/bat.ps1:

# sure would love not to have to redefine all the common params() here...

. common.ps1 <pass-the-arguments>

Common-Func-Uses-Params $specific_Foo/Bar/Bat_Data
```

As the pseudo-comments above indicate, I've only been able to do this so far by capturing the params in the calling script as well.

I want to be in a situation where I can update the common code (say with a `-Debug` or `-DryRun` or `-Url` or whatever parameter) and not have to worry about updating all of the client code to match.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing two key things:

- **`args`** - which captures all of (and only) the unbound arguments to the script
- **splatting** (**`@`**) - which is used to pass arrays or hashtables to a command rather than flattening them like you'd get with **`$`**

When you combine these, you can easily pass all arguments onto another script, like so:

```
# foo.ps1

. common.ps1 @args
```

With a sourced file like this:

```
#common.ps1

param ([string]$foo = "foo")
echo "`$foo is $foo"
```

You get these output:

`> foo.ps1` returns `$foo is foo`

`> foo.ps1 -Foo bar` returns `$foo is bar`

---

Note that, if you're trying to use the PowerShell ISE it might take you a while to figure this out or debug any of it. When you're in the debugger, both $args nor $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments will do their best to hide that information from you. They'll appear to be completely empty.

You can print the args with `>> echo "$(@args)"`, but that also provides the very weird side effect of telling the Debugger to continue. I think the splatting is adding an extra newline and that's ending up in the Command Window.

The best workaround I have for that is to add `$theargs = $args` at the top of your script and remember to use `$theargs` in the debugger.